# Переписать код из Java 7 в Java 8

Tags: java

Есть код (Java 7):

```
Set<Session> set = new HashSet<>();
for (Session session : this.sessions.values()) { // sessions -> HashMap<String, Session>
    if (session.isSavingRequired()) {
        session.setSavingRequired(false);
        set.add(session);
    }
}
```

Как переделать код выше в вариант java 8 ?
Я пробовал так:

```
Set<Session> set = this.sessions.values()  
                   .stream()  
                   .filter(Session::isSavingRequired)  
                   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Проблема в том, что в коде выше я пропускаю строку `session.setSavingRequired(false);` что не есть хорошо. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Или так:

```
Set<Session> set = this.sessions.values()  
                   .stream()  
                   .filter(Session::isSavingRequired)
                   .peek(s -> s.setSavingRequired(false))
                   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит применять потоки данных всегда и везде. Если алгоритм требует *состояния*, значит функциональный подход не для него.

Comment: Взял на заметку. Скорей всего оставлю так, а код ниже возьму на заметку для других целей.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать следующим образом:

```
Set<Session> set = this.sessions.values()  
               .stream()  
               .filter(Session::isSavingRequired)
               .map(session -> {
                 session.setSavingRequired(false);
                 return session;
               })
               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Плохая идея, `map` не должен мутировать данные. Это может приводить к непредсказуемым ошибкам.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Согласен, тогда лучше использовать метод `peek` как предложил @Roman Danilov.